# How to make a fixed header which is not moving when scrolling?

Tags: scroll, header

I have tried almost every answer in similar thread, but could find anything that works for me.

I have following site:

1. A header (div span over the full width).
2. A left column.
3. A right column.

The header and the right column are fixed.

I would like the text in the left column to disappear beneath the header when scrolling.

Something like I see on many websites where a header with a message (ex. "accept cookies") stays on a fixed place.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
    <div id="head">
    <!-- here is the code of our header -->
    </div>
    <div id="content">
    <!-- The next block for example with the main content -->
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
    #head{
        width: 1000px;
        height: 60px;
        position: fixed;
        background: #fff;
        z-index: 1000;
    }
    /* So that our next block does not run under the header, as soon as the page is loaded, add an indent. */
    #content {
        margin-top: 60px;
    }
```

Comment: This is not working.
Everything, including the header is scrolling.

Comment: If I add "overflow: hidden;" it works.
The code looks like this:

.header{
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}

But I would like to have the right column fix as well.
Right column should not scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Everything works now.

Left column scrolling with fixed header:

```
.header {
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color: black;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Right column fixed (responsive):

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .rightcolumn {position: fixed;}
}
```